# Which query should i use?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to learn mysql properly. When i have a query using 2 tables, Do i need to write table names before the field name all the time?

**This is the one i have got**

```
SELECT 
owner.title, owner.forename, owner.surname,
pet.name, pet.breed
FROM
owner,pet
WHERE
owner.owner_id = pet.owner_id
ORDER BY
owner.surname ASC, pet.name ASC
```

**if i do this way is it ok aswell?**

```
SELECT 
title, forename, surname,
name, breed
FROM
owner,pet
WHERE
owner.owner_id = pet.owner_id
ORDER BY
surname ASC, name ASC
```

Comment: I'd say none of the above. USE an `INNER JOIN` instead of the whera a.id=b.id. the were a.id=b.id hides the intent; inner join makes it very explicit on what fields you are joining. It improves readability

Comment: wrong. both queries are correct

Comment: @baris22 You can always alias table names if you don't want to type long table names. Example: `select a.title, a.forename, a.surname, b.name, b.breed from owner a, pet b where a.owner_id = b.owner_id order by a.username, b.name`

Comment: @PanayotisMatsinopoulos, implicit join syntax is unhelpful because it makes it hard to debug complicated queries, separates the join criteria from the tables that are joined, makes it hard to rewrite an inner to an outer join and a number of other reasons *cogh* accidental cross joins *cogh*. Best to avoid them like the plague.

Comment: @PanayotisMatsinopoulos, besides query 2 will give an error if table `owner` also has a field named `name`. So qry2 is **less correct** than qry1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 1992, this:

```
FROM
  owner,pet
WHERE
  owner.owner_id = pet.owner_id
```

is (by SQL-92 standards) written as:

```
FROM
    owner
  JOIN                         --- or the equivalent: INNER JOIN
    pet
      ON owner.owner_id = pet.owner_id
```

---

To answer your question, I would prefer the first choice (modified as above) over the second, mainly for readibility. Someone else may have to read your code (or you, after a few days or months) and knowing which table every column belongs can be useful:

```
SELECT 
  owner.title, owner.forename, owner.surname,
  pet.name, pet.breed
FROM
    owner
  JOIN
    pet
      ON owner.owner_id = pet.owner_id
ORDER BY
  owner.surname ASC, pet.name ASC
```

Another reason is to catch the case you (or someone) later adds (or renames) columns on the tables and you have a "name clash" which will make your query either give error and stop working or give different than expected results.

---

You could also use aliases, like this:

```
SELECT 
  o.title, o.forename, o.surname,
  p.name, p.breed
FROM
    owner AS o
  JOIN
    pet AS p
      ON o.owner_id = p.owner_id
ORDER BY
  o.surname ASC, p.name ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

Best form in my opinion would be something like this (and remember, form is largely subjective):

```
SELECT o.title, o.forename, o.surname, p.name, p.breed
FROM pet p 
INNER JOIN owner o ON o.owner_id = p.owner_id
ORDER BY o.surname ASC, p.name ASC
```

I find queries like this the most readable and easiest to modify.  If I have multiple tables in a query, I **always** alias my tables and I always use that alias in the field selection.  The kind of query I wrote is also a fairly portable query, meaning it uses pretty basic SQL features and syntax, so you could take it to another DBMS and you probably wouldn't have to change anything.

Comment: @baris: You have learned how to join tables. But using the old, very old, way.

Comment: @baris22: if this is for a class, then do it the way your instructor wants you to do it.  But I still stand by my answer here as being the "right" way to do what you're trying to do.  And remember, it's easy to create new habits, it's hard to change established habits.  Do this correctly from the start and you'll have a much easier time down the road.

Comment: Having worked more than 10 years in teaching SQL, I would think that your teacher would not complain if you used the `JOIN` syntax. Or have both ways as options, just in case he had a bad day :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use table names. But if you are accessing multiple tables, there is a likelihood of column clashes - in which case it is helpful to specify which table you mean.

Some db systems (notably PostgreSQL) will complain if it isn't sure which column you are referring to.

Comment: All DBs will complain if they can't figure out which field you're using.

Comment: You are right. Both queries are correct, but your answer justifies well why you should get used to use table names.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks Marc. I think I had in mind the varying behaviours when using SELECT * - most dbs will rename duplicate column names (so name becomes something like name_1), whereas PostgreSQL doesn't auto-alias.

Answer (score 0):

If both table contain the same column name then you need to specify the table name with column  name to prevent ambiguous situation, other wise it's not needed.